# Object returning NaN when using a simple sum

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sum

I have 2 values which i try to subtract from one another. One comes from my firebase DB and the other from a form filled in by the user which is a sum of a table row.

this is what i mean to illustrate this:

```
var total = 0;
var HoeveelheidArr=[];

    $('#resultTable .Repetities > input ').each(function() {
        HoeveelheidArr.push($(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < HoeveelheidArr.length; i++) { //my arrawy from user input which i extracted
        //console.log("setAmount:", setAmount);
       // total += parseInt(HoeveelheidArr[i]) * parseInt(setAmount);
       total += parseInt(HoeveelheidArr[i]);
    }
```

thats for the total variable, here is my other varible, this variable is from my firebase DB and is made from my iot device. it is just a simple number that start from 0 and gets incremented on a certain event. It is also here that causes the error:

```
var progressList = document.getElementById("progressList");
var wemosRep = function(element, value){ //function update content from elemnt with value
    element.textContent = value;
}

//get value from db and auto pass update if change in value
var startWemosRep = firebase.database().ref('Reps/Value');
startWemosRep.on('value', function(snapshot){
    wemosRep(progressList,snapshot.val());
});

//my sum generating the error
var progressLeft = parseInt( startWemosRep - total ) ;

// writing the value to the DB Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'Exercise.totalRepsLeft'
firebase.database().ref("Exercise").set({
    totalRepsLeft: progressLeft,
});
```

Do you see what im doing wrong?

Comment: The code that is *outside* of your event handlers will run exactly once, when your script is first loaded.  Thus `total` will always be 0, and `startWemosRep` will be an object reference, and subtracting the former from the latter will always give you `NaN`.

Comment: I see, would including it in the event handler solve it in that case?

Comment: Moving that global code into event handlers is definitely a good idea, though I don't know enough about what your intent is to give specific advice.